# Wrong action link generated in view which is inside area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

[image]

I am using main _Layout.cshtml for my Index.cshtml which is in "Areas -> Views -> Home".
due to this links for logoff & login are generated wrong (which are inside main _LogOnPartial.cshtml).

i.e. it is generated as "http:// localhost/Admin/User/LogOff" but It should be generated as "http:// localhost/User/LogOff"

_LogOnPartial.cshtml code

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <text>
        @* Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!*@

        @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "User", null, new { @class = "btn btn-action btn-first" })  </text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>@Html.ActionLink("Log In", "Login", "User", null, new { @class = "btn btn-action btn-last" }) @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "User", null, new { @class = "btn btn-action" })</text>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: How do you generate your link?

Comment: It is same logic which we use in _LogOnPartial.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate urls that do not target an area, you need to make sure the area route value is cleared. You can achieve that by setting the area route value to an empty string.

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "User", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-action btn-first" })
```

This way no matter if the view you are rendering is inside an area or not, the links in the shared partial will always be generated for the "root" controllers.